# Weird ouput using Popen in ST3

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3, popen

I'm developing a plugin for Sublime text and due some limitations of python in that environment I'm trying to get an json answer with Popen, I receive the data correctly, but seems like Popen is adding some weird characters in the output.

**This is the ouput**

```
(b'{"trink": {"id": "12"}}\r\n')
```

**but it should be**

```
{"trink": {"id": "12"}}
```

This is how I make the call:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
output = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

With

```
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

only disappears the () from the original output

How can I get an clean output?

*I'm using Sublime text 3 Build 3083
Windows 10-64b*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user in the ST forum answer me:

> For starters, this is 100% a Python issue and has nothing to do with
>   Sublime Text. It's also not a limitation but a feature. Literally.
>
> Firstly, communicate returns a tuple with (stdout_data, stderr_data).
>   You most likely only need the stdout part, so you slice that tuple
>   with `[0]`.
>
> Secondly, the data that communicate returns is, by default, a set of
>   bytes. Look that up if you want. Bytes are represented with the `b` in
>   front of a literal string and can be converted to real strings using
>   the .decode() method on it, with a parameter for the charset. This
>   could be utf-8 or cp1252 or just the result of
>   `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. If you used Popen with the
>   `universal_newlines=True` argument, Python would do that conversion
>   for you automatically.
>
> And finally, the string you have until now has a new line appended at
>   the end, because that's how whatever tool you are using made its
>   output. You have to strip it with .strip(), if it's a problem (since
>   it's json, most likely not).
>
> So what do we get now?
>
> ```
> process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
> output = process.communicate()[0]#.strip()
> print(output)
> ```